# Django logging throws 500 internal server error

Tags: python, django, logging

I am having problems logging in my Django project.

In my `view.py` in an "application" I am doing the following:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="django.log",level=logging.DEBUG)

def request(request):
    logging.debug("test debugging")
```

with a `django.log` file in the same directory as the `view.py` file.

Now when making a request from the browser I keep getting a 500 Internal Server error as shown in Firebug. I can get logging to work just fine when I simply run it through the interactive python shell or executing it from a `.py` file like the following:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="django.log",level=logging.DEBUG)

def testLogging():
    logging.debug("test debugging")

if __name__ == "__main__"
    testLogging()
```

, and then executing `python nameOfFile.py`.

What am I doing wrong? I am running Django 1.1.1 and Python 2.6.5. Maybe I should upgrade Django?

Comment: What is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error?  Can you supply more information?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be related to permissions? I can imagine that in a web-server environment, writing to a file may be restricted. In truth, I don't know, but please check the official [Django logging documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) - it uses the standard logging module, but you may have to configure it differently.

Comment: Logging was added to Django in the most recent dev version.  There is no logging in Django 1.1.1, which the OP mentioned he is using.  And yes, that means the title of the question is misleading.  (He appears to just be using the logging module in the Python std library.)

Answer (score 1):

Is that your entire view? It would have been helpful to post the actual traceback, but note that a view must return an `HttpResponse`, even if it's an empty one. So if that is your entire view, the 500 error is probably happening because you're not returning anything.

Add `return HttpResponse()` to the end of that view, and if that still doesn't work, please post the traceback itself.

Comment: I am returning and just didn't include for the sake of brevity, I apologize for not mentioning that. I upgraded to django 1.2.5 and also placed the django.log file to /var/log/  . Is there a way to include it in the application folder itself? where the views.py is. Changing permissions to the file still results in Permission Denied when including it in the app folder.